# Equivalent definitions of total variation norm

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, total-variation, signed-measures

Let $E$ be a set, $\mathcal E\subseteq2^E$ with $\emptyset\in\mathcal E$ and $\eta:\mathcal E\to\mathbb R$ with $\eta(\emptyset)=0$. If $B\subseteq E$, let $$|\eta|(B):=\sup\sum_{i=1}^k|\eta(B_i)|,$$ where the supremum is taken over all $k\in\mathbb N$ and disjoint $B_1,\ldots,B_k\in\mathcal E$ with $\bigcup_{i=1}^kB_i\subseteq B$.

> I want to show that $$|\eta|(E)=\sup_{B\in\mathcal E}\left(\eta(B)-\eta(B^c)\right)=\sup_{B\in\mathcal E)}\left(|\eta(B)|+|\eta(B^c)|\right)\tag1.$$

If necessary, impose further assumptions on $\mathcal E$ (e.g. $B_1\cup B_2\in\mathcal E$ for all $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal E$) or $\eta$ (e.g. additivity).

I guess we can somehow argue by considering $B=\bigcup_{i:\eta(B_i)\ge0}B_i$.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\eta$ instead of $\mu$ in $(1)$?

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, sure.

Comment: @RhysSteele I'm not sure what you mean by "modulus signs".

Comment: Ah whoops, actually my comment was just dumb. The expression is the same with or without an absolute value.

Comment: @RhysSteele No problem. Let me know if something is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I'll assume that $\mathcal{E}$ is closed under finite unions and complements and that $\eta$ is finitely additive. Note that you really use that $\mathcal{E}$ is closed under complements for the result you want to make sense so these are only the additional assumptions formulated in your question.

Then the result is trivial from your suggestion. Indeed, for disjoint $B_1, \dots, B_k \in \mathcal{E}$, let $B$ be defined as in the question. Then 
$$\sum_{i=1}^k |\eta(B_i)| = \eta(B) - \eta(B^c) = |\eta(B)| + |\eta(B^c)|$$
by finite additivity. Now taking the $\sup$ in each of these terms gives the result.

---

It's also obvious that both finite additivity of $\eta$ and $\mathcal{E}$ being closed under unions are necessary.

If you don't assume that $\mathcal{E}$ is closed under finite unions then consider $E = \{0,1,2,3\}$, $\mathcal{E}$ to be the set containing $\emptyset, E$, all singletons in $E$ and all three element subsets of $E$ and set $\eta = \delta_0 + \delta_1 - \delta_2 - \delta_3$. Then it is easy to check that $|\eta|(E) = 4$ but 
$\sup_{B \in \mathcal{E}} |\eta(B)| + |\eta(B^c)| = 2$. Note that this $\eta$ is even the restriction of a signed measure to $\mathcal{E}$.

If you assume that $\mathcal{E}$ is closed under finite unions but $\eta$ is not additive things also go wrong. For example, let $E = \{0,1,2,3\}$, $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{P}(E)$ and set $\eta(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\eta(A) = 1$ for all other $A \in \mathcal{E}$. Again we have that $|\eta|(E) = 4$ and $\sup_{B \in \mathcal{E}} |\eta(B)| + |\eta(B^c)| = 2$.

Comment: (a) Closed under complements and $\cup$-stable, so a ring. That's what we really need, right? (b) Where did you use *countable* additivity? Seems like finite additive should be enough.

Comment: (c) By the same argument, we should be able to deduce $$|\eta|(B)=\sup_{A\in\mathcal E}(\eta(A)-\eta(B\setminus A))=\sup_{A\in\mathcal E}(|\eta(A)|+|\eta(B\setminus A)|),$$ for all $B\in\mathcal E$, right?

Comment: (a) I need it to be a ring that contains the whole space (since the definition of a ring of sets I've read is only closed under relative complements). (b) sorry, that was just a typo. Meant to write finite additivity there, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yes, you're right. We need it to be an algebra if we want to choose $B=E$ in (c).

Comment: (c) I think you want to take the $\sup$ over subsets of $B$. Otherwise you can take $B$ to be a null-set and $A$ to have positive measure. If you do that the result is true. You can either use the same argument again or also deduce that from this result directly by replacing $E$ with $B$ and $\mathcal{E}$ with $\{A \in \mathcal{E} : A \subseteq B\} = \{ A \cap B: A \in \mathcal{E}\}$.

Comment: Right, the trace $\sigma$-algebra. Thank you!